# Difference between "it's" and "its"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, possessives

I wrote an essay and it contained a lot of `it's`. Upon doing a grammar check on it, all the `it's` were suggested to be replaced by `its`.

I am currently not much familiar with the difference between the two. And when to use which one?

Comment: ***its*** = *belonging to it*. ***it's*** is an abbreviated form of ***it is***. ALWAYS.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Or *it has*.  "It's been fun!"

Comment: @snailcar♦: Oops! I now regret and have cancelled my closevote (as "lacking research"). That's ***two*** important facts about ***it's*** that wouldn't necessarily be easy for a learner to find by casual Internet search - your point, and the one alluded to in my comment under Vsevolod IV's post (about not being able to use the abbreviated form as the ***final*** element in an utterance).

Comment: I wonder how you could possibly write an essay and not know the difference.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A: Whose is that? Is it his?

B: No, its it is

its --> belonging to "it"

it is --> it's (contraction)

Comment: Native speakers would be *very* unlikely to come out with that reply (except perhaps "facetiously").

Comment: Wow! Seriously?:p This wasn't meant to be GRAMMATICALLY correct, I only posted it to show how the two work SYNTACTICALLY

Comment: It's "grammatically" fine. But ***idiomatically*** it's avoided, which imho makes it a poor example to present to learners (who might not realise they shouldn't copy it).

Comment: ...I also believe that grammatically / syntactically it would be perfectly possible (but non-idiomatic) for B to reply ***No, its is it*** or ***No, its it is***, and there may even be recorded written instances of either or both. I don't know if it's actually "ungrammatical" to reply ***No, its it's***, but I'm quite sure there won't be any written instances of that version.

Comment: Point taken. I'll edit it according to the recommendations given. Thank you!:)

Comment: Nice Answer (+1). But i didn't understand the first two sentences!! I understood the third and the fourth one (in which actual difference is stated).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica This is more to do with the inversion, which is perhaps seen as old-fashioned (?). As a reply to "Whose is that? His?", both "No, it's *its*." and "No, it is *its*.", with some emphasis on the last word would even be acceptable, I'd say.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S The second utterance features some sort of inversion: suppose "This is Bob's" is the original, then "Bob's, this is" would be a construction equivalent to the one in this answer. Both of these mean the same thing.

Comment: @userr2684291: Native speakers normally avoid using "existential **it**" and the "true pronoun" in close proximity. You can certainly *repeat* it providing both usages are semantically / syntactically equivalent, as in ***It's** true that **it's** raining*, or *The dog's hungry. Give **it it's** food*. But the close juxtaposition of two ***different*** senses is inherently awkward, so most speakers would go to some considerable lengths to find another way of conveying the intended meaning.

Comment: (But I'm not gonna argue against things like [*The trouble with security is that **it's its** own enemy*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it%27s+its+own+enemy%22), where ***own*** helps distinguish between the two consecutive uses.)

Answer (score 2):

`it's` - contraction of `it is`, `it has` or like as `where is` or `there is`

`its` - possessive form of `it` and use to say that something belongs to or refers to something like `my` or `your`.

**For example:**
`He doesn’t think its a good idea to spend all his money on video games.` - incorrect
`He doesn’t think it’s a good idea to spend all his money on video games.` - **correct**

`Its been a year since the last time they met` - incorrect
`It’s been a year since the last time they met` - **correct**

`The computer looked as though it’s power supply had failed` - incorrect
`The computer looked as though its power supply had failed` - **correct**

`A car is no good without it’s wheels` - incorrect
`A car is no good without its wheels` - **correct**